# Pythonic way of checking bit values

Tags: python, python-2.7, flags

I have this set of constants declarations

```
    self.POUTPUT = 1
    self.PPWM = 2
    self.PINPUT = 4
    self.PUNUSED = 8
    self.PSONAR = 16
    self.PULTRA = 32
    self.PSERVOD = 64
    self.PSTEPPER = 128
    self.PCOUNT = 256
    self.PINPUTDOWN = 512
    self.PINPUTNONE = 1024
```

What is the pythonic way of checking whether a value matches any of the input states (4,512 and 1024) please?
Extra info: I'd normally just use bit pattern checking in simpler languages but I wondered if there was a better way in Python :)
Basically it is that each pin can have one of the I/O states above but if a pin is any of of the input values then one action occurs
e.g if pin == 4 or 512 or 1024  -> do something

Comment: Doesn't that miss the point of checking bit values? You usually want to check `if bit 3 is set in the number N` ignoring the rest of the bits, not test `if N is in (4, 512, 1024)`. If you really want the latter, just use the normal `if N in sequence:` syntax.

Comment: Im assuming he really does want to just check a bit (as opposed to a match) since all of those values are `1<<n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing for set membership (which is what you seem to be doing) is best done using a `set`.

```
self.input_states = {self.PINPUT, self.PINPUTDOWN, self.PINPUTNONE}

# later
if value in self.input_states:
    do_something()
```

Of course you could handle this in a variety of essentially-identical ways, but one way or another you have to encode some knowledge as to which of these magic numbers are "input states".

---

Now if, as has been suggested, what you actually want is to do some bit-masking or tests based on whether a particular bit is set, then you want to take a look at the [Python bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). In particular, to see if a value is equal to one of the ones you've got there, you'd use the bitwise and, which is denoted by `&` in Python. [Joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22518491/2069350) covers this use well, but the basic idea is:

```
if value & self.PINPUT: # Value has a 1 in the PINPUT bit (bit 3)
    do_something()
```

Or if all of those input values trigger the same action:

```
if any(value & p for p in (self.PINPUT, self.PINPUTDOWN, self.PINPUTNONE)):
    do_something()
```

Comment: almost gave you minus one but its not clear ... the title sounds like he wants to check a bit in an integer.... but the he asks about matching ... so i dunno (+1 just in case he is actually trying to do set testing)

Comment: @Joran I agree; the question could definitely use some elaboration, but I think it's mostly just a misleading title: the "checking whether a value matches any of the input states (4, 512 and 1024)" seems reasonably clear.

Comment: but those are all bit key positions `1<<n`  I suspect he really does just want to check if a bit is set and not if the value is equal to the define

Comment: note: the `set` test works only if *"each pin can have [exactly] _one_ of the I/O states"*. If would fail if the value may correspond to several states at once e.g., file permissions such as `0o755`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if SOME_DATA & self.PINPUTNONE:  # do somethign
```

is how people usually do it

to check alot

```
ANY = self.POUTPUT | self.PPWM | self.PINPUT | self.PUNUSED |  self.PSONAR  ...
if some_data & ANY: #do something
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: how much faster is `bool(x&y)` versus `x==y` ?

Comment: those are not equivalent statements at all.... although for this data perhaps would be

Comment: of course they're not equivalent, but this is apparently what OP is trying to do, so in this case -- speed difference?

Comment: marginally faster ... probably not fast enough to be worth using as a substitute if you actually want to check equality